# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel doesn't show up even with different cell styles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableView *)table {
    if (!_table) {
        _table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [_table setDelegate:self];
        [_table setDataSource:self];
        [_table registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    return _table;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    else

    [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is when I `registerClass` for my table, it assumes that my cell style is `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. So that's why `detailTextLabel` doesn't show up. I tested it.

Comment out the `registerClass` line doesn't work because I don't have any `CellIdentifier` for `dequeueReusableCell`. So it will throw some exceptions.

If I'm not using `dequeue`, it works, but it not the best practice.

AFAIK, table cell couldn't change its style after init. So how can I make the `detailTextLabel` show up ?

Comment: Your code looks like it doesn't need the registerClass.

Comment: Very well-posed question. You've worked on the problem before posting and have correctly and clearly deduced the source of the difficulty.

Comment: @CrimsonChris in my question, I already mentioned in my question that not registering any class with identifier will causes exceptions because I don't have anything to `dequeue`. Do you have another way to do it ?

Comment: There are plenty examples of cell reuse where you don't register a class. I have never once registered a cell class in all my production code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is when I `registerClass` for my table, it assumes that my cell style is `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. So that's why `detailTextLabel` doesn't show up

That is correct. The solution is: do not register UITableViewCell as your class. Register a custom UITableViewCell subclass whose sole purpose in life is that it initializes itself to a different style.

For example, register the MyCell class, which you have defined like this:

```
@interface MyCell:UITableViewCell
@end
@implementation MyCell
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
   reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 // or whatever style you want
                reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: And see my full discussion here, which is the source of that code: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_registering_a_cell_class

Comment: thanks matt, your answer is correct. However, do you have another way to do it without subclassing `UITableViewCell` ? i like it stays nice and neat in my controller's code :D (also, without using `UILabel` :D, because it's too easy)

Comment: You could use a nib / storyboard as the source of the cell instead of a class. That way you can set the style in Interface Builder.

Comment: But my point is, if you are going to register a class, then a subclass is the only way to dictate the style. It's a mistake that Apple made when they created the entire "register a class" mechanism. They should have allowed you to register a class _and_ set a style, but they didn't.

Comment: clear enough, I prefer to code than use xib/storyboard. I've hard time trying to understand it. Anyway, this is out of topic but do you have any realizable source/tutorial for using storyboard ? thank you.